# Apache Cassandra CQL - Drop Multiple Tables

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cassandra, cql

I have a query that I am running on Jupyter with Python 3 kernel. But I am getting an error. The code+query:

```
import cassandra

from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect()


query = """
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS song_info_by_session, songs_played_by_user_in_session, user_info_by_songs_listened;
"""
try:
    session.execute(query)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

And the error is:

```
<Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 2:41 no viable alternative at input ',' (DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [song_info_by_session],...)">
```

It is my first time using Cassandra and I couldn't find any info if it is possible or not to drop multiple tables in one query, so I wanted to check if I have another error unrelated with this feature, or I got error due to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doc: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlDropTable.html#Synopsis

It is only possible to DROP one table at a time, so you will have to run each DROP statement individually.